# Ajax Post before send function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i dont know how to write before send function 
following code

```
$.post(
            "<?=URL?>filter-subcat.php",
             {
                service:service_arr,
                facility:facility_arr,
                product:product_arr,
                location:location_arr
             }, 
             function(data){
                var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#result').html();

                $("#result1").html(result);
                $("#result1").addClass('active');
                $("#loader").html("");
                $("#shops").html(data);
             },
             function(beforeSend)
            {

                $(".modal_1").show();
                $(".fade_1").show();
            },
            function(complete){
                $(".modal_1").hide();
                $(".fade_1").hide();
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below format

```
$.ajax({
                  beforeSend: function() { 
                                //code to execute before sending request
                  }, //Show spinner
                  complete: function() {
                   // code to execute after ajax completion 
                  },
                  url: url,
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  headers: { //if any},
                  data: {},
                  success: function (data){ 

                  },
                  error : function (data){  
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `beforeSend` with `$.post()`, instead you can use `.ajaxStart()/.ajaxComplete()` methods but these should be bound to `document` not the elements:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
     $(".modal_1, .fade_1").show();
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
     $(".modal_1, .fade_1").hide();
});
```

If you want to use `beforeSend` then you have to use `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"",
    type:"",
    dataType:"",
    beforeSend:function(){},
    success:function(){},
    error:function(){},
    complete:function(){}
});
```

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali check the version added: **version added: 3.0**.

Comment: Opps, you're right. Thanks for pointing it. Numbering quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Jquery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

as you see you have to use $.ajax() function, actually you code is a mix of both with some errors

```
$.ajax( {
  method: "POST",
  url: "<?=URL?>filter-subcat.php",
  data: { 
        service:service_arr,
        facility:facility_arr,
        product:product_arr,
        location:location_arr
        },
  done:function(data){
      var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#result').html();
      $("#result1").addClass('active').html(result);
      $("#loader").html("");
      $("#shops").html(data);
 },
 beforeSend:function(){
      $(".modal_1,.fade_1").show();
 },
 always:function() {
      $(".modal_1,.fade_1").hide();
 },
 error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert( "error" );
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}})
```

Comment: _You should read the Jquery documentation_....same goes for you too....go to the docs and see what errors have you posted?

Comment: yup sorry, i am gone too fast, i updated my post, thanks !

Comment: thanks its working but 
after response come the loader not hide

Comment: can you post me the loader of your html plz ? by the way i changed a bit the code to show you how to reduce lines